# Change Eclipse template for auto-generated main method?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

When I create a new class in Eclipse Juno and auto-add a `main` method, I get the following:

```
public class Example {

  /**
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }    
}
```

I would like to edit this method template to add `throws Exception`.

I tried editing the template at **Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates > "main"**, however this doesn't affect the scenario above. Instead, this configures the code which is inserted when I type "main" and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I know for creating your own new class / new project template, is by creating your own plugin. This requires some effort. I am not sure if it is worth doing it only for adding a throw to main.

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120321084857/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-pde/) is a tutorial for it.

Comment: Hey @Vishnu, try out the below answer. It might help.

Comment: @Vishnu I've edited the link with the Internet-Wayback-Machine, so its working again.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is too late for an answer. Hopefully, someone else finds it useful.

I was trying to do this exact same thing. I wanted to do something like

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example sol = new Example();

    }    
}
```

What I ended up doing is, configuring a code template which auto-generates the above for me.

Edit template at **Preferences > Java > Code Style > Code Templates > Code >  Class Body > Edit**

Adding the following template pattern, lets me generate what I needed

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ${type_name} sol = new ${type_name}();
    }
```

For your use case, writing the below template should do it.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    }
```